# Python behaves differently in command line and eclipse with pydev

Tags: python, macos, csv, pydev, xlsxwriter

I am writing a python script on a mac with OS X 10.7.5 which reads data from csv file using built in csv module and writes to a xlsx file using the xlsxwriter module. It works perfectly when executed within eclipse with pydev. But when called from command line the script chokes on the string "Rodríguez" which contains a unicode character and throws up this message.

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 54, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 365, in write
    return self.write_string(row, col, *args)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 57, in cell_wrapper
    new_args = list(xl_cell_to_rowcol(args[0]))

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/utility.py", line 80, in xl_cell_to_rowcol
match = range_parts.match(cell_str)

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I checked the version of python on both the environments and it is the same.

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

What might be wrong here? Is there any other settings which needs to set in command line?

Comment: Can you show (part of) the code itself, not just the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Add this as the first line in your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details